# Mongoengine serialize dictionary (with nested dicts)?

Tags: dictionary, serialization, django-rest-framework, restframeworkmongoengine

I've created a dictionary from an Uploaded file in Django.

This dictionary has a nested list of dictionaries:

```
file = {"name": "filename", "sections": [{"section_name": "string", "lines": [{line_number: 0, "line"; "data"}]}], "etc": "etc"}
```

The model represents the dictionaries depth too.

```
class Line(EmbeddedDocument):
    line_number = IntField()
    line = StringField()
    definition = ReferenceField(Definition)


class Section(EmbeddedDocument):
    section_name = StringField()
    lines = EmbeddedDocumentListField(Line))


class File(Document):
    name = StringField()
    sections = EmbeddedDocumentListField(Section))
    created_on = DateTimeField()
    created_by = StringField()
    modified_on = DateTimeField()
    modified_by = StringField()
```

In the **POST** I have the following to chop the file up into the above Dict (the file is a simple text file):

```
file= {}
with open(os.path.join(path, filename + ".txt"), 'r') as temp_file:
    filelines = temp_file.readlines()
    sections = []
    section = {}
    lines = []
    for i, l in enumerate(filelines):
        if i == 0:
            section["section_name"] = "Top"
        elif '*' in l:
            if l.index('*') == 0 and '*' not in lines[len(lines) - 2"line"]:
                section["lines"] = lines
                lines = []
                sections.append(section)
                section = dict()
                section["section_name"] = filelines[i + 1][1:-2]
   line = {"line_number": i + 1, "line": l}
   lines.append(line)
   section['lines'] = lines
   sections.append(section)
   file["name"] = filename
   file["sections"] = sections
```

I will tidy this up eventually.
Once the dict has been made how do I serialise it using the serializer?

Is it possible to insert this into a serializer?

If not how can I get it all into the database with validation?

I've tried `json.dumps()` and `JsonRequst()` then putting them in `data=` for the serializer but get `Unable to get repr for <class '....'>`

I'm pretty new to Django and MongoDB so if you need more info I can provide :)

Thanks!

**Update**

Change the model's List Fields to EmbeddedDocumentListField as suggest in the answer.

**Answered**

Thanks to Boris' suggestion below it pointed me to an error I wasn't getting initially. I had a typo and passing the dict directly into `FileSerializer(data=file)` works like a charm! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

James!

The easiest way to validate that your incoming JSONs adhere to the Mongoengine Documents schema that you've specified is to use DRF-Mongoengine's `DocumentSerializer`.

Basically, what you need to do is create a serializer

`serializers.py`

```
import rest_framework_mongoengine

class FileSerializer(rest_framework_mongoengine.DocumentSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = File
```

Then you need a view or viewset that makes use of this Serializer to respond to GET/POST/PUT/DELETE requests.

`views.py`

```
from rest_framework_mongoengine import viewsets

class FileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'id'
    serializer_class = FileSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return File.objects.all()
```

and register this viewset with a router

`urls.py`

```
from rest_framework import routers

# this is DRF router for REST API viewsets
router = routers.DefaultRouter()

# register REST API endpoints with DRF router
router.register(r'file', FileViewSet, r"file")
```

I'd also recommend using `EmbeddedDocumentListField` instead of `ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Section))` - it has additional methods.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The serializer has been made already. Probably should have made it a little more clearer.
The viewsets is a good one and EmbeddedDocumentListField! I'll give that a try now and update.

Comment: Additionally As mentioned, how do I get the dictionary made from an uploaded file into the serializer? That is the main part.
I'm already in the POST for the upload

Comment: @JamesBellaby In your viewset you specified `serializer_class = FileSerializer`, right? Your viewset consists of a GenericView and mixins, one per REST method. When you POST your data to that viewset, it calls `create()` method from `CreateModelMixin`, which constructs your serializer from `serializer_class` attribute, passes it the input data and calls `seiralizer.is_valid()`, which performs validation and `serializer.save()`, which saves the validated data to the database: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L18.

Comment: There may be a missunderstanding here. I have sent a request to upload a file, that file is then read and chopped up into the dictionary (OP).

This means I've already had a request sent and I'm in a REST POST method dealing with the file to make the dictionary.
So how do I then get the dictionary to the serializer.

Every time I try it says it 'Unable to get repr'

Do I call the URL from the POST method as "localhost/"?

Comment: When you send a request, django rest framework's handler determines, which http method was used and calls the corresponding method of your viewset. Its router also parses the url arguments, extracts `lookup_field` - which defaults to primary_key of your database - and (if given) passes it as an argument to the viewset method.

Comment: To simplify further, I'm not sending a dictionary as a request from elsewhere, the dictionary is made in Django from a file upload request.

Comment: As for the file uploads: normally I do it in 2 steps. First, I upload the file metadata, then I upload the file content itself. As for the error you get - could you show me your code on Github or anywhere?

Comment: I'm not asking how to upload a file. I've done that!
I'm asking.... how do I put a dictionary into a serializer?

Forget the request, forget telling me how Django Rest handles request, How do I serialize a python Dict that isn't in `request.data`

Comment: Updated the OP with code that is in the POST that handles the dictionary creation.

Comment: @JamesBellaby To pass data to serializer, you just pass it in its initializer: `serializer = self.get_serializer(data=my_data)` or just `serializer = FileSerializer(data=my_data)`. Then normally you say `if serliazer.is_valid(): serializer.save()` and this either returns an error or saves your data to the database. Sorry that I didn't understand the point of your question at first.

Comment: No problem, OK, I've tried `serializer = FileSerializer(data=my_data)` that presents the `repr` error.
I haven't tried `self.getserializer` though. I'll test that now.
FYI, I would love to Github this but it'd be frowned upon :(

Comment: @JamesBellaby Don't do `json.dumps(data)` - just pass the raw python dict to the serializer - `data` is meant to be a python `dict` or `OrderedDict`.

Comment: In doing this as a ModelViewSet it pointed me to the underlying issue thanks to a much better error message.
It was a type in my serializers `Meta.model` class
After all that! haha
Appreciate the help @BorisBurkov

Comment: @JamesBellaby Great! Cheers :)